# Building a list of n length same value Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to `build/3` a list in Prolog of `N` elements, each element should be `X`.

```
?- build(30,3,L).  
L = [30,30,30].
```

Spent a good few hours on it, keep ending up in either a infinite loop or the variables aren't instantiated properly.

```
build(_,0,[]).  
build(X,N1,[X]):- N1>0, N1 is N - 1, build(X,N,[]).  
build(X,N1,[X|L]) :- N1 > 0, N1 is N - 1, build(X,N,L).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```erlang
build(_,0,[]).         % any value, repeated 0 times, makes for an empty list
```

good.

```erlang
build(X,N1,[X|L]) :-   % a value X, repeated N1 times, makes for [X|L] list, _if_ ...
  N1 > 0, N1 is N - 1,    %  N1 is positive, and L is
  build(X,N,L).           %  one element shorter... right?
```

<s>excellent.</s> huh? `N is N1 - 1` you mean.

```erlang
build(X,N1,[X]):- N1>0, N1 is N - 1, build(X,N,[]).
```

why?? `[X]` is already matched by the previous rule, `[X] = [X | [] ] = [X | L]`, and the empty list `L = []` will be matched by the first rule.

You don't need this rule ***at all***.

Answer (score 9):

Using meta-predicates makes it very short:

(1) with `maplist/2`: creates a list of length N and then matches all its elements to X.

```
build(X, N, List)  :- 
    length(List, N), 
    maplist(=(X), List).
```

(2) with `findall/3`: makes loop N-times and completes List with X N-times

```
build(X, N, List)  :- 
    findall(X, between(1, N, _), List).
```